# Edit get_post_meta() output in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

In a WordPress site, I want to remove the last 4 charaters (included space) in the rendered output of `get_post_meta`.

Here is the PHP code, where I output the custom field named `key` of a post:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'key', true);
wp_reset_query();
```

Example:
If in a specific post, `key` is `My song title mp3`, the output will be `My song title` because `mp3` has been trimmed.

Comment: All you want to do it is to remove last 4 characters irrespective of what it is from key. Right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your echo command with:

```
$string = get_post_meta($postid, 'key', true);
echo substr($string, 0, -4);
```

which saves the post meta as `$string`  then uses substr() to remove the last 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code:

```
global $wp_query;

$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$key    = 'My song title mp3';
$key    = substr($key, 0, -4);

echo get_post_meta( $postid, $key, true );
wp_reset_query();
```