# How can I add a default value to custom field in addition information tab woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added a custom field that is getting and displaying the value on the front-end. The issue arises when the field is empty or the value is 0, it shows empty on the front end. I want to display '0.00' instead of empty. Is there any switch statement that can go in the code? or what

```
function corecharge_woocommerce_display_product_attributes($product_attributes, $mproduct){
    $product_attributes['corecharge-field'] = [
        'label' => __('Core Charge', 'text-domain'),
        'value' => get_post_meta($mproduct->get_ID(), '_number_field', true),
    ];
//  echo var_dump($product_attributes);
    
    return $product_attributes;
    
}
```

[Show 0.00 instead of empty on addition information tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GDHt.png)

Comment: Since WooCommerce 3, you should use `get_meta()` method instead of WordPress `get_post_meta()` as WooCommerce is progressively migrating to custom database tables, for better performances. So replace `get_post_meta($mproduct->get_ID(), '_number_field', true),` with `$product->get_meta('_number_field'),`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by handling the return value of [`get_post_meta`<sup>*WP-Function*</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

For example in your case turn it into your default value `'0.00'` in case it returns *falsy*:

```php
get_post_meta($mproduct->get_ID(), '_number_field', true) ?: '0.00'
                                                          #########
```

The "switch statement or what" here is the [ternary operator `?:`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), with the middle part left out (its *shorthand* form).

This allows to have a default value with `get_post_meta()` when called for a single value (third parameter, `$single`, is `true`).

As it returns `false` if the post-meta is not found, the right-hand side, here the default value, is taken.

If the single post-meta field is set to an empty string `""`, the number zero or a string containing the number zero (e.g. `"0"`), it a is also *falsy* and the default value is taken.

Compare:

- [How do I use the ternary operator ( ? : ) in PHP as a shorthand for "if / else"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1506527/367456)
- [Edit get_post_meta() output in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40632499/367456)
- [if get_post_meta is empty do something](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56597/178)

Comment: Thanks! It worked exactly how I wanted it to. Stackoverflow rocks :D

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote if you find it useful as well. Your question was borderline with existing content, but as far as I could see there was no default for get_post_meta() so far, so I added it. This is independent to woocommerce and works with any wordpress `get_post_meta()` and similar functions that can return `$single`.